# On using Titanium parallel dialect of Java

Tags: java, parallel-processing, titanium

> Titanium is an explicitly parallel dialect of Java developed at UC
>   Berkeley to support high-performance scientific computing on
>   large-scale multiprocessors, including massively parallel
>   supercomputers and distributed-memory clusters with one or more
>   processors per node [[berkley](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/)].

The link is probably one of the few sources that says something about the project. Searching this site(stackoverflow) have hardly anything to say about this seemingly new parallel dialect of Java.

My question is:

- Are you using this language to develop parallel applications?
- What is your experience developing parallel application using Titanium as compared to - say- Hadoop MapReduce

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Well, it _is_ the answer to the question, and the rep is lost anyway, so might as well post it as an answer.

Comment: I think this question, and especially the general "what are your experiences" part, is too broad for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As countless linux distributions , the Titanium "framework" was built with the same role : **fit the creator's needs** first , given at that at the time there weren't as many possibilities to choose from.
- The project is almost **20 years old** ( started around '96-'98), so realising how much technology has evolved in the last couple of years , it's obvious that even though the concepts they used are still to be found, the implementation isn't nearly as up-to-date .
- So comming back to the first point .This is not to critique or judge UC Berkeley' creation since a lot of effort has been put into it but any programmer who cares about his projects will try to keep up and use the latest technologies available going for softwares like `Apache's Hadoop MapReduce` , **Apache** being known for creating frameworks to **fit the needs of the programmer**.
  Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm not using this language. And I tell you that, it is better to use something that is on boom now. try with [GridGain](http://www.gridgain.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I can whore for buttons with the best of you ...

No; that Titanium has never really escaped from the research lab and it is not being widely used, if at all, for developing parallel applications. You seem to think that Titanium is new, but work on it started in the latter half of the 1990s; since then an aeon has passed in terms of parallel programming languages and systems. If anyone on the planet has properly compared Titanium with Hadoop/MapReduce I'll eat one of my hats